# Get data from php to angularjs doesnt working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm new in Angular I want to get a SQL request from php script to angular, but I see only a big bulleted list and I dont know what is the problem.

My html code:

```
.
.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js">
</script>
<script src="../js/proc_list.js"></script>
.
.
.
<div align="center" id="prod_list" ng-controller="proc_list">

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="processor in proc">
    {{processor.manufacturer}}
    <p>{{processor.description}}</p>
    {{processor.price}}
    </li>
</ul>   

</div>
```

Controller code:

```
function proc_list($scope, $http){
$http.post('../phps/get_proc_list.php').success(function(data){
        $scope.proc = data;
    });
}
```

PHP code:

```
$received_data = file_get_contents("php://input");

$objData = json_decode($received_data);

require_once('login.php');
.
.
//Connect to database and send query
.
.
 $data_requested = json_encode($data);

echo $data_requested;
```

I tried to do similar like this link:http://www.cleverweb.nl/javascript/a-simple-search-with-angularjs-and-php/

but its still not working. Anybody has any idea?
Thank you

Comment: Start checking if the data is correctly post to the php script. Then check if the php script generate some valid response and so on. Only with snippets its hard to say which component of your application cause the problem. It is correct that you dont post any data to the server? What the sense here, use GET!

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax of $http.post is `$http.post('/someUrl', data).success(successCallback);`

Read more about in the AngularJS docs: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#post](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#post)

Comment: Originally it was $http.get request I tried this one as well, but yeah I know this is not valid format, but actually I replaced back to get, but still doesnt working.

Comment: generate the php script a valid response?

Comment: Yeah it1s look like ok: http://webstore.mauritiusbeachhouses.com/phps/get_proc_list.php

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's working now in this case not need to encode to json the $data, just simple send it back